# Is it necessarily true that $\|B^{-1}\|$= $1/\|B\|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

If we have an invertible operator $B$ from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$, is it necessarily true that $\|B^{-1}\|= 1/\|B\|$?

I think the answer is no. We are on Rudin's Principle's of Mathematical Analysis's Chapter 9.

Using Theorem 9.7, which states if $A\in L(\mathbb{R^n},\mathbb{R^m})$ and $B\in L(\mathbb{R^m},\mathbb{R^k})$, then 
$$\|BA\| \leq \|B\| \|A\|.$$

Thus we have:
$\|1\|=\|B^{-1}*B\|\leq \|B^{-1}\|\|B\|$. Thus $\|1\|/\|B\| \leq \|B^{-1}\|$.
So we have $\|B^{-1}\| \geq \|1\|/\|B\|$.

Thus I get that $\|B^{-1}\|$ can be **greater than or equal to**  $1/\|B\|$.  However, I'm not sure if $B$ being an invertible operator specifically from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$ makes it just equal to (and not necessarily greater than. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left\|\pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}\right\|=2,\quad\left\|\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1/2}\right\|=1$$

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I thinking too. But can I consider $M_2(R)$ to $M_2(R)$ when we are considering $R^{2}$ to $R^{2}$? Or in other words, are these equivalent?

Comment: No, linear maps $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ themselves correspond to $2\times2$ matrices.

Comment: Oh I see, great thanks, I was slightly confused.

Comment: Last question, this may be a very simple question, but I never learned this: how do we calculate the norm of  a matrix, i.e. why does the norm of the matrix on the right equal 1? Thanks!

Comment: @kemb: A simple inequality will show you that $\|Ax\| \le \|x\|$, and equality is attained for $x = (1,0)$.  Similarly, you can conclude that for any diagonalizable matrix, the operator norm equals the absolute value of the largest eigenvalue: $\|A\| = \max_i |\lambda_i|$.

Comment: Great.  I just looked that up and it said the same thing. Thank you.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: That statement about the norm of a "diagonalizable matrix" needs some adjustment.

Comment: Yes, I should have said "orthogonally diagonalizable".  Sorry.